# Random behavior differences between C# and Java: the seed

Tags: c#, java, math

I have a Random into a class which aims to generate random sequences in different contexts: this is the result of a porting from Java code.
In the Java version everything works fine since the java.lang.Random class has the method setSeed, which permits the change of the seed value dynamically.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
...
rnd.nextInt();
...
rnd.setSeed(seedValue);
```

This generates a consistent result, since each time the seed value is set, the result is random.

Unfortunately in C# the behavior is much different, since the Random class needs the seed to be set at construction:

```
Random rnd = new Random(seedValue);
...
rnd.Next();
...
```

So I have to build a new Random instance each time with the given seed, which in some spare cases generates the same value of a previous call.

Is it a way to set the seed of a Random instance in C# dynamically, without losing the consistency of the instance globally?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it really necessary to re-seed? It should be "random enough" as it is.

Comment: unfortunately it is: the instance of Random is a member of a class, which is called in different parts of the class and need to be consistent within all the instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't expect to have `setSeed` called more than once on a `Random` during runtime. *FreeCell* does it so that you can "load" game instances by writing down the seed that was used.

If you change seeds, it should be like *resetting* the Random instance and thus there should be no conflict if you reinstanciate it. `Random` is just a wrapper on an underlying algorithm.

If you want to receive different results each time (even if you USE  setSeed), you might try this:

```
class MyRandom {
  private Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

  public void setSeed(long seed) {
    random = new Random(seed * this.random.next());
    ...

  public long next() {
    return random.next();
}

class MyClass {
  private MyRandom random = new MyRandom();
  public void Test() {
    random.setSeed(seedValue);
    int x = random.next();
    random.setSeed(seedValue);
    int y = random.next();
    // x,y will be different in most of the cases now
  }
}
```

This will change pre/postconditions of how seeds for random generators should work but might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I create a single instance of Random for my application and after setting the seed on instantiation can rely on each call to Next giving me a new random number. The trick is to make sure the seed is as random as possible. The use of Random in a C# app is a good example of where a Singleton is a good fit.

There are a variety of ways to get differing strengths of randomness in your seed and there are some good SO questions dealing with that.

The example below is the approach I use.

```
m_randomURL = "https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randnum?num=1&min=1&max=1000000000";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_randomURL);
StreamReader stIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
Random rand = new Random(Convert.ToInt32(stIn.ReadToEnd()));
```

random.org uses atmospheric noise to generate the randomness and is apparently used for lotteries and such.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the Random instance, as pseudocode:

```
class MyRandom {
   private Random random;

   public void setSeed(long seed) {
        random = new Random(seed);
        ...

   public long next() {
        return random.next();
```

Comment: this is what I'm doing at the moment (in the ported version) and doesn't fix the issue: as I said, I should not re-initialize the instance of "random"...